# Including errors in gaussian process regression

Tags: machine-learning, gaussian-process, measurement-error

I am a new machine learner and am trying to use a Gaussian process regression approach on a training set with ~ 60,000 samples and two features. For the features I have the errors in each sample.

I am using sci-kit learn and I believe this would be done using the 'alpha' kwarg in the GaussianProcessRegressor but it does not want to take a multifeatured matrix for alpha.

The documentation isn't super clear to me about this as all the examples are for 1 feature cases, can someone who is more familiar say whether you can have independent errors for the different features? If I can't have the feature errors independently is a covariance or reduced error (cf. reduced mass) a better approach?